# Android: provide own implementations of java.* classes for jar

Tags: android, jar

I have a .jar in my Android project which has many references and uses of the java.awt.* classes and other classes not available on Android. How can I provide my own implementations of these classes so that I can embed the unmodified .jar file (the only modification is being ran through dx) in my Android application and it will use my own class implementations?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't.  Classes in your .apk *must not* be in the java.*, javax.*, android.*, and com.android.* namespaces.  An application can't replace system classes, and if you have classes in those namespaces that aren't currently defined by the system you run the risk of breaking in the future if a class of the same name appears.